# Are masses additive at the quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass

When learning quantum mechanics, it seems like many of the assumptions that we have from the macroscopic scale do not necessary apply. Do we have proof that masses are additive at the quantum scale? That is to say is it possible that the mass of two particles might be different from their sum?

Comment: Yes. I recommend you to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect)

Comment: What do you mean by the "mass of two particles"? Are you just considering a system of two non-interacting particles or are they bound to each other, like in an atom?

Comment: @Arthur I forgot about that. I mean two particles combining without changing energy (possible?) and asking if their total mass is known to be equal to their sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the  quantum frame one is also in the special relativity frame. Mass in this frame is the "length" of the [fourvector describing](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) either individual particles or a system of particles. 
$$
\vec P = \begin{bmatrix}E\\p_xc\\p_yc\\p_zc\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}E\\\vec pc\end{bmatrix}
$$
In special relativity it is the four vectors  which add, not the masses, and the combined four vector
$$
\sqrt{P\cdot P} = \sqrt{E^2 - (pc)^2} = m_0c^2
$$
will have a mass larger than the sum of the individual masses , unless the particles are completely at rest.

As we are talking quantum mechanics, and the [Heisenberg Uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) holds, the probability that( even for two )particles they all have zero momentum with respect to each other, is small, So even for very cold particles there will always be a small fuzziness which will make the sum of the particles invariant masses smaller than the system's invariant mass.

This so far is about free non interacting particles.

In quantum mechanics interacting particles may bind with each other in a potential well, as in the hydrogen atom, or in the binding of a proton and a neutron to make a deuteron. In that case the mass of a system of particles becomes smaller by the  binding energy as in this [nuclear binding energy curve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Binding_energy_curve_-_common_isotopes.svg)  The sum of the nucleon masses is larger than the summed mass of the nuclei.

And to complicate matters further, the quantum mechanics theory that describes the protons and neutron and hadrons in general, quantum chromodynamics,

> [Most of the mass of hadrons is actually QCD binding energy,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics_binding_energy#Source_of_mass) through mass-energy equivalence. This phenomenon is related to chiral symmetry breaking. In the case of nucleons – protons and neutrons – QCD binding energy forms about 99% of the nucleon's mass. That is if assuming that the kinetic energy of the hadron's constituents, moving at near the speed of light, which contributes greatly to the hadron mass, is part of QCD binding energy. For protons, the sum of the rest masses of the three valence quarks (two up quarks and one down quark) is approximately 9.4 MeV, while the proton's total mass is about 938.3 MeV. For neutrons, the sum of the rest masses of the three valence quarks (two down quarks and one up quark) is approximately 11.9 MeV, while the neutron's total mass is about 939.6 MeV. Considering that nearly all of the atom's mass is concentrated in the nucleons, this means that about 99% of the mass of everyday matter (baryonic matter) is, in fact, chromodynamic binding energy.

In conclusion, special relativity is crucial in determining masses at the quantum mechanical level.